# Discriminant of a $V_4$-extension of local fields is the product of discriminants of intermediate fields

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

**Edit:** I have also posted this question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460608/reference-request-discriminant-of-a-v-4-extension-of-local-fields-is-the-prod), since it did not receive any answers on MSE.

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of $p$-adic fields with Galois group $V_4 = C_2 \times C_2$, and write $d_{L/K}$ for its discriminant, which is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$. The extension $L/K$ has three quadratic intermediate fields $E_1,E_2,E_3$. I would like a reference for the fact that
$$
d_{L/K} = d_{E_1/K}\cdot d_{E_2/K}\cdot d_{E_3/K}.
$$
This is true because of the conductor-discriminant formula; we know that
$$
d_{L/K} = \prod_{\chi} f(\chi)^{\chi(1)},
$$
where $\chi$ ranges over the irreducible complex characters of $V_4$, and $f(\chi)$ is the conductor of this character. The trivial character has conductor $1$. The three nontrivial characters $\chi_1,\chi_2,\chi_3$ correspond to the extensions $E_1/K, E_2/K, E_3/K$, and $f(\chi_i) = d_{E_i/K}$, again by the conductor-discriminant formula. The result follows.

This argument is quite long-winded, and referencing it properly would make it even longer. Can anyone give me a reference for the fact?